# データフレームの中の大文字で書かれた要素のみ抽出する

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Information1' : [19, 'Shopping','HANA', 'Canada'],
               'Information2' : ['books', 24, 'games', 'MARY'],
               'Information3' : ['JACK', 'Italy', 'Japan', 23],
               'Information4' : ['Australia', 'MARCO', 25, 'movies']},
               index = {'Person1','Person2','Person3', 'Person4'}
               )
```

このdf1をprintすると、以下のようになります。

```
        Information1    Information2    Information3    Information4
Person3    19              books           JACK           Australia
Person4   Shopping          24             Italy           MARCO
Person1   HANA             games           Japan            25
Person2   Canada            MARY            23             movies
```

このPerson1,Person2, Person3, Person4の列の中から大文字のみで示されている名前の要素のみ取り出す方法はあるでしょうか(str.upperを使う方法もうまく思いつきません)
理想としては、

```
        Name
Person3 JACK
Person4 MARCO
Person1 HANA
Person2 MARY
```

のようなかんじです。もし何か有効な方法があれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 大文字のみで示されている名前の要素が複数ある場合にはどの様になるのでしょうか？(リストにする？)

Comment: 掲示のコードの通りに df1 を作成すると、print された結果と中身が違ってしまいますが。。。print 通りだと仮定して、`pd.DataFrame(df1.apply(lambda x: filter(lambda i: type(i) == str and i.isupper(), x), axis=1), index = df1.index, columns = ['Name'])` など。ただし、条件を満たす要素が一つの場合でもリストになります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。大変失礼いたしました、コードを修正いたしました。そのようなやり方があるのですね！ちなみに、リストにしない場合、新たな列(Name2)などを追加してそこに二つ目の名前を入れることは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: できなくはないでしょうが、要素が一つしかない行の `Name2` には何を入れれば良いでしょう？(空文字 か None(null)？)

Comment: さっそくの回答ありがとうございます！要素が一つしかないものに関しては、回答してくださった条件をつけてNoneをいれる方法がとても分かりやすいです！このisupperも初めて目にしたもので、勉強になりました(^ ^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データフレームを、

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Person1' : [19, "books", "JACK", "Australia"],
                'Person2' : ["shopping",24 ,"Italy" , "MARCO"],
                'Person3' : ["HANA", "games","Japan", 25],
                'Person4' : ["Canada","MARY",23 ,"movies"]}
                  )
df1 = df1.T
print(df1)

                0      1      2          3
Person1        19  books   JACK  Australia
Person2  shopping     24  Italy      MARCO
Person3      HANA  games  Japan         25
Person4    Canada   MARY     23     movies
```

という構造だとして、

1. 左の列から順番に探して一番最初に見つけた大文字を取得する
2. 大文字が見つからなければ`None`を入れる

と言う条件なら、`hasattr`を使いながら下記のような出来るかと思います。

```
Name = []
for row in df1.itertuples():
    for item in row:
        if hasattr(item, "isupper") and item.isupper():
            Name.append(item)
            break
    else:
        Name.append(None)
df1["Name"] = Name
```

ワンライナーでできそうな気もしますが、そこまではちょっと分かりません。